# Anyone know why I'm not seeing options in fluid type?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, fluid-simulation

[image]I'm using this youtube tutorial for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=370Q4COgMqo

I've been able to set the domain cube, but cannot set the 'fluid' or 'particle' option. I can only see the options: none, domain, flow and effector. I've just downloaded blender today so I should have all the options? But they're not coming up? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So what *do* you see? Please [edit] your question to add additional details/images. Thanks.

Comment: Edited- thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest to look for a more up to date tutorial regarding "Mantaflow", as that is the system used in the newer version of Blender. There are a good few tutorials available online. Another option if you want to follow this specific tutorial, would be to use the older version of Blender in this case 2.80(a for a stable version), as that version still used the older fluid system.